# TS - Cannot pass argument from const - how to use "as const" with arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to pass nested object as method argument. Inline everything works, but passing variable will result in TS error because for example `{ a: 'x' }` will become `{ a: string }` instead. Solution for that is to use `as const` on that variable. But this does not work on objects with arrays etc. I'm forced to use 'as const' multiple times INSIDE that object, instead just doing 'as const` at the end. Why?

```
type A = 'xxx' | 'yyy' | 'zzz'

type Demo = {
    a: A,
    b: number,
}[]

const demoMethod = (demo: Demo) => {
    console.log(demo)
}

/* Example #1 - OK */
demoMethod([
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 },
    { a: 'yyy', b: 222 },
    { a: 'xxx', b: 333 },
])

/* Example #2 - ERROR */
const demo2 = [
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 },
    { a: 'yyy', b: 222 },
    { a: 'xxx', b: 333 },
]
demoMethod(demo2)

/* Example #3 - OK */
const demo3 = [
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 } as const,
    { a: 'yyy', b: 222 } as const,
    { a: 'xxx', b: 333 } as const,
]
demoMethod(demo3)


/* Example #4 - ERROR */
const demo4 = [
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 },
    { a: 'yyy', b: 222 },
    { a: 'xxx', b: 333 },
] as const
demoMethod(demo4)
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkAPNSoB9klx7SAXsUgFCmiRQAiEAtgPYJQDepUHUAhgFywA07TgCM+AOwCudYRABOggL4BtALrkAxgzEBnYFAAm9BgFkIwABYN9zABSHGfWowCUCAHyshHTToYAbCAA6PwYAczsjZ1IFcgB6ACooAFEULjowAKgAYgBGKABaKAB5AGkoeNjSexMzS30bJS9Wbj5UdH4oUSgcnqgFQU5m3hw8Dq6AJkm+gc4WFuQ0FCQxvgBmdenSFSjSBOTU9Mys8YLkgCUzorPyyp9dAyMTxEbBueG2pZXu3v6mt9bcCBlp0+JMTr9XvMPsCuutVps1NVTBYrBFGOMdnsUmkMtAsvDCqUbqQ7npqvDnn8oYsYXwenkFNxtFBSTMOP8RkCvmC+kyWVpdGyhq0aV84byuMzWVsqkZkXU0QxVjtdolsYc8QAWU5JC5XYmkh6MbWUyHvUUg74MoUcpCA2lQHkQ2bU9qW8W-FR80myxjy1HVTUqoA)

It does not make any sense for me that even that example #1 and #2 are 100% the same, #2 does not work and I'm forced to change my data using multiple 'as const' instead passing it at it is. Is there any better solution to force TS to treat my const argument same way as inline argument?

Edit: Note that I have defined type and method only in my example purposes. In real life this method comes from external package, and without exported type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you don't have access to the type, you can try to retrieve it using [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

```js
type a = Parameters<typeof demoMethod>[0];
// Which gives
// type a = {
//    a: A;
//    b: number;
//}[]
```

Then use type annotation for example!

**Previous response**

Instead of using `as const`, you could do `const demo5: Demo = ...`.

It will then check that the value you give to `demo5` corresponds to the type `Demo`.

```js
const demo5: Demo = [
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 },
    { a: 'abc', b: 222 }, // TypeError: Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type 'A'.
]
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=11&pln=48&pc=14#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)

In general, it is better to avoid `const a = ... as Demo;` because Typescript won't do any check and just assume that `a` is of type `Demo`.

```js
const a = 'Hello world!' as number; // Won't raise an error
const a: number = 'Hello world!'; // Will raise a type error
```

Answer (score 1):

Example #2 does not work because `demo` is inferred as `{ a: string; b: number; }[]`. This is clearly not assignable to `Demo`, which is `{ a: A; b: number; }[]`. You have to either explicitly tell TypeScript that `demo` is of type `Demo` with a type annotation like @Cr4zySheep said, or use `as`:

```
// type annotation
const demo2: Demo = [
    { a: 'xxx', b: 111 },
    { a: 'yyy', b: 222 },
    { a: 'xxx', b: 333 },
] as Demo; // or use 'as'

demoMethod(demo2);
```

**Below fixes example #4**

Readonly arrays are not assignable to regular arrays.

This is because regular arrays are mutable. If you provide an immutable array to something that expects a mutable array, that clearly is a type mismatch. However, regular arrays can be assigned to immutable arrays, because regular arrays don't *have to be* mutated.

```
type Demo = ReadonlyArray<{
    a: A,
    b: number,
}>;
```

So here would be the proposed solution; just use a readonly array.